# How to add check box as well as simple node in same tree view with java swing

Tags: java, swing, jtree

1) how to add simple node (without check box control) in Jtree.

2) Or how to add Check Box node(with check box control) in Jtree.

3) all node is add in seam Tree using java swing.

4) Please suggest me for this task .

following is code sample :

public class DynamicTreeView extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener {

```
// cerate varible  
//private CheckTreeSelectionModel selectionModel;
private JTree tree;
private JTextField textBox;
private JButton btnCreateNode;
private JCheckBox chkNode, ch1;
private JScrollPane ScrollPan;
private JPanel pane, pane1;
private DefaultTreeModel model;
private JCheckBox check;
int hotspot;

public DynamicTreeView() {
    hotspot = new JCheckBox().getPreferredSize().width;
    //cerate Panel object  
    pane = new JPanel();
    //cerate JTextField object  
    textBox = new JTextField(10);
    //cerate JButton object  
    btnCreateNode = new JButton("Create Node");
    //cerate JCheckBox object  
    chkNode = new JCheckBox("Has CheckBox");
    //add componet all to  panel
    pane.add(chkNode);
    pane.add(textBox);
    pane.add(btnCreateNode);
    //Register button object
    btnCreateNode.addActionListener(this);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    //Cerate the Default Root Tree node for Tree
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Java Tree Example");
    //Cerate the tree object with Default Root Tree node 

    tree = new JTree(root);
    //get the module from tree and add to the DefaultTreeModule
    model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
    //cerate scrollpane object with tree
    ScrollPan = new JScrollPane(tree);
    //scrollpane object add to the form
    //use the border lay out for this form scroll pane is add to the left side of the form
    getContentPane().add(ScrollPan, BorderLayout.WEST);
    //panel object add center of the form
    getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

//Main method of the class it's the staring point of the class.
public static void main(String args[]) {
    //set default look of the form on start position.
    DynamicTreeView frame = new DynamicTreeView();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (btnCreateNode.equals(e.getSource())) {

        if (chkNode.isSelected() == true) {
            ch1 = new JCheckBox(textBox.getText());
            TreeCellRenderer render = new TreeCellRenderer() {
                @Override
                public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
                    Component returnValue;
                    if ((value != null) && (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
                        Object userObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
                        ch1.setText(textBox.getText());
                        ch1.setSelected(selected);
                    }
                    returnValue = ch1;
                    return returnValue;
                }
            };
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ch1);
            JTree t = new JTree();
            t.setCellRenderer(render);
            MutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(t);
            //model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
            TreePath path = tree.getSelectionPath();
            //MutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
            MutableTreeNode node = (MutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
            //model.insertNodeInto(cr, node, node.getChildCount());
        } else {
            CheckRenderer cr = new CheckRenderer();
            cr.setNode(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(textBox.getText()));
            model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
            TreePath path = tree.getSelectionPath();
            MutableTreeNode newNode = cr.getNode();
            MutableTreeNode node = (MutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
            model.insertNodeInto(newNode, node, node.getChildCount());
        }
    }

    SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            ((DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel()).reload();
            tree.revalidate();
            tree.repaint();
            ScrollPan.setViewportView(tree);
            return null;
        }
    };
    sw.execute();
}
```

}

Comment: See also [`CheckBoxNodeTreeSample`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CheckBoxNodeTreeSample.htm).

Comment: without looking at your problem: your SwingWorker is **wrong** - doInBackground is for stuff done in the the worker thread and _must not_ access any ui-related instances